# Composer Playground not connecting to a real fabric

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am new to blockchain and trying Playground for my first Blochain application. I followed this [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/playground-tutorial.html).

As soon as I click "deploy", I get a pop-up on screen saying "error:error trying install business network. Error: The business network is already installed on all the pears.

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off not using hyperledger composer, it's been end of life for a long time and no one uses it and so there won't be anyone who will be able to help you or willing to invest any time to help you. I would suggest you look at hyperledger fabric (which hyperledger composer used to require to provide the blockchain capability as hyperledger composer is not a blockchain technology but an application framework).

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Also this guide may be useful

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/full-stack-asset-transfer-guide